# How to delete (drop) an Oracle AQ queue?

Tags: plsql, oracle-aq

I wish to drop an Oracle AQ queue and the table associated with it.

What are the commands needed to perform this operation?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In order to delete the **queue** and the **table** associated with it, the steps are:

1. Stop the queue
2. Drop the queue
3. Drop the queue table (optional)

The following command will remove the queue *and* table.

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_AQADM.STOP_QUEUE(queue_name => 'QUEUE_NAME');
  DBMS_AQADM.DROP_QUEUE(queue_name => 'QUEUE_NAME');
  DBMS_AQADM.DROP_QUEUE_TABLE(queue_table => 'QUEUE_TABLE_NAME');
END;
```

You don't *need* to drop the table, but it is usually the case when executing this operation.